# Generate SOAP request

Tags: java, soap

I tried to generate the below SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:loc="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/data/sync/v1_0/local"> 
<soapenv:Header/> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<loc:syncOrderRelationResponse> 
<loc:result>0</loc:result> 
<loc:resultDescription>OK</loc:resultDescription> 
</loc:syncOrderRelationResponse> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And I'm using the following code:

```
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage outgoingMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soappart = outgoingMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soappart.getEnvelope();

        envelope.setAttribute("xmlns:loc" , "http://www.csapi.org/s");
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
        QName bodyName = new QName("", "syncOrderRelationResponse", "loc");
        SOAPBodyElement purchaseLineItems = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);


        QName childName = new QName("","result","loc");
        SOAPElement product = purchaseLineItems.addChildElement(childName);
        product.addTextNode("0");

        childName = new QName("","resultDescription","loc");
        SOAPElement product = purchaseLineItems.addChildElement(childName);
        product.addTextNode("0");
```

When I execute the code I get no response,but when I put the namespaceURL I got the response.

could you please help me?
thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You get an XML error because your use of namespaces is not coherent throughout your process, and ultimately results in an XML specification violation.

First things first :

```
envelope.setAttribute("xmlns:loc" , "http://www.csapi.org/s");
```

Means you add to your document a namespace prefix declaration (the `loc` prefix) that designates the namespace identified by `http://www.csapi.org/s`.

This implies that from now on, if you declare an XML element using this syntax `<loc:tag>`, then `tag` is an XML element that belongs to the `http://www.csapi.org/s` namespace.

When you subsenquently declare a QName this way

```
QName childName = new QName("","result","loc");
```

You are preparing an XML element that has 3 caracteristics :

1. It belongs to the empty namespace (first argument)
2. Its local name in the empty namespace is "result" (2nd argument)
3. You want its local name to be prefixed with "loc" (3rd argument)

Which is OK (at least, the implementation thinks so)... Untill you add this QName to your document : at this point in your XML document, the "loc" prefix does not designate the empty namespace. So you are, in effect, asking the XML implementation to redefine the "loc" prefix to mean "empty namespace" in order to comply with your statement. But the empty namespace is special in XML, it can not be prefixed (see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-using)

> In a namespace declaration for a prefix (i.e., where the NSAttName is a PrefixedAttName), the attribute value MUST NOT be empty.

However, please note that, given your example, that's actually fortunate because "adding a <result> element from the empty namespace" is NOT what you want to do. What you want to do is add a result element from the "http://www.csapi.org/s" namespace.

Therefore, a consistent namespace handling provides you with the expected result :

```
String namespace = "http://www.csapi.org/s";

SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

QName bodyName = new QName(namespace, "syncOrderRelationResponse");
SOAPBodyElement purchaseLineItems = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);


QName childName = new QName(namespace,"result");
SOAPElement product = purchaseLineItems.addChildElement(childName);
product.addTextNode("0");

childName = new QName(namespace,"resultDescription");
product = purchaseLineItems.addChildElement(childName);
product.addTextNode("0");

outgoingMessage.writeTo(System.out);
```

Outputs a valid representation of what you are seeking.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <syncOrderRelationResponse xmlns="http://www.csapi.org/s">
     <result>0</result>
     <resultDescription>0</resultDescription>
  </syncOrderRelationResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Although if you really want the namespace prefix to appear, you can do it so :

```
String namespace = "http://www.csapi.org/s";
String nsPrefix = "loc";

envelope.setAttribute("xmlns:" + nsPrefix , namespace);
SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

QName bodyName = new QName(namespace, "syncOrderRelationResponse", nsPrefix);
SOAPBodyElement purchaseLineItems = body.addBodyElement(bodyName);


QName childName = new QName(namespace,"result", nsPrefix);
SOAPElement product = purchaseLineItems.addChildElement(childName);
product.addTextNode("0");

childName = new QName(namespace,"resultDescription", nsPrefix);
product = purchaseLineItems.addChildElement(childName);
product.addTextNode("0");
```

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer if it has been helpfull to you